# How to set attribute namespace "xml:lang" in Java

Tags: java, xml, exist-db

I can easily add attribute namespace for xmlns:lc
But how to set attribute namespace for xml:lang
This is how i set xmlns:lc:

```
Document doc = createEmptyDocument();
doc.normalizeDocument();
Element pubElement = doc.createElement("publication");
pubElement.setAttributeNS(XMLConstants.XMLNS_ATTRIBUTE_NS_URI, "xmlns:lc", "http://.../lc");
pubElement.setAttributeNS(XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI, "xml:lang", "http://www.w3.org/XML/2000/10/xml.xsd");
```

I've search in stackoverflow about this question, but none of the answers helped

Comment: Have you tried just [setting an attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), `pubElement.setAttribute("xml:lang", "yourLang");`?

Comment: yes, i've tryed. But did not work for me.
What i've also tried is 
`doc.createElementNS(XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI, "xml:lang");
       pubElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xml",XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI);
       pubElement.setAttributeNS(XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI, "xml:lang", lang);
        pubElement.setAttribute("xml:lang", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace");`

Comment: I think that you are trying to create attribute with name `"xmlns:lc"` in namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"`; that's not a valid attribute name. You should just use the attribute name without namespace prefix, i.e. `pubElement.setAttributeNS(XMLConstants.XMLNS_ATTRIBUTE_NS_URI, "lc", "http://.../lc");` and `pubElement.setAttributeNS(XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI, "lang", "http://www.w3.org/XML/2000/10/xml.xsd");`. (The two prefixes are already associated with the namespace name by default.)